# DNN5 Shows Under Construction

Tags: sql-server, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5

I recently upgraded my PC from Windows 7 to Windows 8.1 and am now having problems resetting up my local DNN5 environment.

I pulled my DNN5 instance down from a remote git repo, and just finished importing all of the tables/data/stored procedures from the production DB to a local instance.

I have updated the connection strings in the web.config to reflect my new database, but still, no matter what I do, I am getting redirected to `http://localhost/DNN5/Install/UnderConstruction.htm`.

What am I missing?

for completeness, here are my connection strings and a screencap of my db:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="SiteSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=KMCNUTT-7\DWYATTMSSQL;Initial Catalog=DNN5;User ID=sa;Password=******"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="DNN5ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=KMCNUTT-7\DWYATTMSSQL;Initial Catalog=DNN5;User ID=sa;Password=******"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

[image]

Comment: So did my answer provide any additional assistance?

Comment: @ChrisHammond Yes and no - I'll go ahead and mark it as accepted because it has led me further down the path  of a (still) unsolved problem. It actually ran the installer - which appears to have wiped most of the data I copied down the first time. I have not tried re-importing those tables again yet, but I am leaning closer to just continuing with a clean install and moving the modules down separately. :(

Comment: @ChrisHammond thanks for following up, by the way!

Comment: Eh I'd rather help you out than get accepted if it didn't answer your problem! When the installation process ran again, did it create those tables a new database, or did it put files into the existing database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This almost always happens when you are unable to connect to the database from DNN.

Navigate to

```
http://localhost/DNN5/Install/install.aspx
```

and see if it throws a connection error just to be sure.

Is this a local database? If so try using (local)\InstanceName (I assume your instance name is DWYATTMSSQL) so (local)\DWYATTMSSQL

Also make sure that you have SQL authentication enabled in SQL server, instead of Windows Authentication only, which is the default for SQL installations.

Comment: +1 for the activation of the SQL Server authentication on your local instance